# box-sizing x IE7, the last battle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

I've been searching through the web for a solution that can viabilize box-sizing in the IE7 (I know, the year is 2014, but the project (therefore the clients) still demand this). I really need box-sizing because the entire project is responsive.

I found this [boxsizing.htc](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill) and it works pretty well in almost any case. But, unfortunately, it is not my case.
Because I'm using angularjs and I have a div with three columns (children divs with float left) inside and i can click on a button to change the number of columns. When this happens the boxsizing.htc process all its calculations again making my width and height smaller each time I change the number of columns.

So, I thought, angularjs can solve this. I found this [pretty interesting link](http://microblog.anthonyestebe.com/2013-11-30/window-resize-event-with-angular/)

I could adapt that code into this:

```
myApp.directive('resizable', function($window){
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element){
            scope.initializeWindowSize = function(){
                var win = angular.element($window);
                scope.windowHeight = win.innerHeight();
                scope.windowWidth = win.innerWidth();
                scope.sideHeight = scope.windowHeight - 80;

                  /* ie 7 */
                var workArea = angular.element('.workArea');
                var workWidthPadding = parseInt(workArea.css('paddingLeft')) + parseInt(workArea.css('paddingRight')) + parseInt(workArea.css('borderRightWidth')) + parseInt(workArea.css('borderLeftWidth'));
                var workHeightPadding = parseInt(workArea.css('paddingTop')) + parseInt(workArea.css('paddingBottom')) + parseInt(workArea.css('borderTopWidth')) + parseInt(workArea.css('borderBottomWidth'));

                scope.workWidth = scope.windowWidth - 228 - 210 - workWidthPadding;
                scope.workHeight = scope.sideHeight - 60 - 25 - 2 - workHeightPadding;
                console.log('height', scope.workHeight);

            };

            scope.initializeWindowSize();
            angular.element($window).bind('resize',function(){
                scope.initializeWindowSize();
                scope.$apply();

            }); 
        }
    }
});
```

But that code don't solve all of my problems, just when I can relate the div's width or height with window width or height which it is not all the cases.

Finally, I decide, let's make a jQuery plugin. I came up with this:

```
$.fn.boxsizing = function(){
// if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 7.") != -1){

    var thisWidth = this.width(),
        thisHeight = this.height(),

        thisborderLeft = parseInt(this.css('borderLeftWidth')),
        thisborderTop = parseInt(this.css('borderTopWidth')),
        thisborderRight = parseInt(this.css('borderRightWidth')),
        thisborderBottom = parseInt(this.css('borderBottomWidth')),

        thispaddingLeft = parseInt(this.css('paddingLeft')),
        thispaddingTop = parseInt(this.css('paddingTop')),
        thispaddingRight = parseInt(this.css('paddingRight')),
        thispaddingBottom = parseInt(this.css('paddingBottom')),

        newWidth = thisWidth - thisborderLeft - thisborderRight - thispaddingLeft - thispaddingRight,
        newHeight = thisHeight - thisborderTop - thisborderBottom - thispaddingTop - thispaddingBottom;

        console.log(newWidth, newHeight);
        this.css({'width':newWidth, 'height':newHeight});
// }
}
```

This almost worked.
I can't figured how to apply this code in window resize.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('div.FOO').boxresizing();
});
```

Can someone help? I don't know if angularjs can handle alone this kind of stuff or, if I really need this plugin and, how can I make things work in the window resize.

Thank you and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: You could take a look at this: https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Comment: There are several box-sizing polyfills listed here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills Have you tried them?

Comment: I've tried that too, but it didn't work. Damn Ie7 :/

Comment: Spudley, I've tried the Christian "Schepp" Schaefer version. I will try the other one.